# Как написать правильно еxpression-bodied function member в SharpDevelop

Tags: c#

Хочу написать второй метод ToString(Object obj) через лямбда выражение:

```
/// <summary>
/// Позволяет выводить на экран строковые представления объектов.
/// </summary>
public static class Structure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает строковое предсталение объекта.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string</returns>
    public static string ToString(Object obj, string s)
    {
        string result = String.Format("{0}: ", obj.GetType().Name);
        var props = GetType().GetProperties();
        for(var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < props.Length - 1)
            {
                result += String.Format("{0} = {1}, ", props[i].Name, props[i].GetValue(this));
            }
            else
            {
                result += String.Format("{0} = {1}", props[i].Name, props[i].GetValue(this));
            }

        }
        return result + s;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает строковое предсталение объекта.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string</returns>
    public static string ToString(Object obj) => ToString(obj, "");
}
```

Как написать правильно?

Comment: а что собственно не работает?

Comment: Говорит, что в строке с "public static string ToString(Object obj) => ToString(obj, "")" прямо перед "=>" ожидалась ";".

Comment: Я не эксперт но лямбда это типа анонимнй метод а у вас ToString не принимает метод как аргумент

Comment: на C#6, 7 этот код отлично компилируется, где имеется поддержка [expression-body method](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html#AhMiDHst7cIvpuvc.97)

Comment: Я пишу в #Develop 5.1.0.

Comment: Быстрое гугление [показывает](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/issues/532), что SharpDevelop не поддерживает C#6,7. Значит, такая запись невозможна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: И да, то, что вы хотите — это не лямбда. Лямбда — это анонимная функция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну лямбды как бы вот делаются

```
 public string ToString(Func<object, string> func)
            {
                return func.ToString();
            }
```

Вызов

```
ToString( Height => { return Height.ToString(); } );
```

Первый параметр это то что принимает как аргумет а второй то что возращаем

Вроде так норм будет

```
Func<object, string, string> NewToString = (o, e) =>
        {
            return o.ToString();
        };


NewToString(new object g, "Name");
```

Вроде лямбда есть

Answer (score 4):

Быстрое гугление [показывает](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/issues/532), что SharpDevelop не поддерживает C#6,7. Значит, такая запись невозможна.